# How set scrollable view when softkeyword is pop up?

Tags: android, layout

I need to show a view with a TextView to work as an character counter and two EditText. One to enter the subject and the other to enter the message.

But when the keyboard is displayed, the view can not be scrolled. The keyboard hides the lower part of the view.

I need when the keyboard is displayed, the view fits the remaining space and allows the user to click and scroll the view, similar to the view of compose mail of gmail.

Here is my layout that doesn't work for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" >
        </include>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/caracter_counter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:paddingRight="5dip"
                    android:paddingTop="10dip"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/subject"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
                    android:hint="Subject"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLength="@integer/max_length"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edit_message"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/message"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:hint="Message"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in my manifest, but it does not work.

Like this:

[image]

EDIT

I try with this, but not work, the softkeyword not push the scrollview, the second edittext is cover by the softkeyword.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" >
    </include>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/caracter_count"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_subject"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:hint="Subject"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="@integer/max_length"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edit_message"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_message"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.3"
                android:hint="Message"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Get this:

[image]

I try with the all combination with `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"` in the manifest.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" instead of adjustSize.

Comment: @user2369063 I try, but the keyword push the toolbar and the keyword still hides the edittext.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the issue?

Comment: @mvai I post a picture

Comment: Looks like you just need `"adjustResize"` (without anything else). What happens if you set it so? Try and post your manifest file if you are not sure on how to paste that line.

Comment: @mvai My manifes is long, but the part related is:                              <activity android:name="NewDiscussionActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>  --- I try with adjustResize but not work, the softkey cover the edittext and do not possible scroll the view. it took 3 days and does not work.

Comment: And what if you remove the `fillViewport=true` from the ScrollBar?

Comment: @mvai do not work. I try with fitSystemWindows=true, work, but the status bar turn gray...

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem. I used relative layout to fix instead of linear layout and it worked as expected. You may try with relative layout. It won't be difficult since this is a not a complex layout hierarchy.

edit

I tried with your given xml code. did not do any modification to java code. But deleted weights in your components.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- replaced your toolbar with a textview just for testing -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- deleted weightsum -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/caracter_count"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />
        <!-- deleted weightsum -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_subject"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:hint="Subject"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edit_message"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />
        <!-- deleted weightsum -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />
        <!-- deleted weightsum -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this. I think this is what you are looking for. but you will have to remove weights if it is ok with your requirements.

Comment: I change the linearlayout that is within the scrollview; but it does not work, push the toolbar and I can not move the view.

Comment: ah no @mlozdev. you have to change the outer layout to relative layout. inner linear layout won't matter.

Comment: @mlozdev I edited the answer. try this code. this worked and I didn't add anything to the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply and sorry for hard coding the xml file 
the below xml file is working like a charm for me
Try this one know

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/custon_action_calander_new_event" >
</include>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/caracter_count"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="wLHVBSHSD VHHHJBCVJHDBV"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_subject"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="Subject"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.3"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```